# AWS what is the difference between KMS and Secret Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to understand if two AWS tools are used for different things.  If someone knows the different scenarios one should use KMS versus Secret Manager, please let me know.  Thank you in advance and my apologize if the answer is obvious (I am still learning).

Comment: The question makes sense, but it would be good to do some research "Googling" and find out what each of these services do. For each of these AWS provides FAQ and it's quite obvious what they do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

KMS is used to manage encryption keys. Other services integrate with KMS to provide data encryption capabilities.

Secrets Manager is used to store secrets, like passwords. Secrets Manager uses KMS to encrypt your passwords when it stores them.

Comment: Thank you, your response is helpful!